# Como puedo obtener la url completa de una peticion a un servidor de node.js vanilla

Tags: javascript, nodejs, servidor, http

Quiero usar el contructor URL, pero para poder hacerlo requiero tener la url completa. Todos los tutoriales que explican como hacerlo son con Express...

Comment: Podroas describir mejor el problema y poner lo que has intentado y cuales son los errores que tienes?

Answer (score 1):

¡Ya pude solucionar este problema! Les comparto lo que hice:

```javascript
function handler(req,res){

    //Obtengo la URl completa y se lo paso al constructor de URL
    //Para acceder con facilidad a toda la informacion de la URL

    let myUrl = new URL(req.connection.encrypted ? 'https' : 'http' + '://' + req.headers.host + req.url);

    let method = req.method.toUpperCase();

    let Params = myUrl.searchParams;

    res.end("Hola Mundo");

    console.log("Se hizo una petición con el método " + method + " a la ruta " + myUrl.pathname);

    console.log("Query Params: " + Params);

};
```